# How can i limit the user in bigquery to scan data upto 5gb per day?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, quota

I want to set the limit to a user to query data upto 5gb per day in bigquery.

I tried to edit the Quota Query usage per day per user but i didn't find any option to add the specific user whome i want to restrict.

Is there any way to set up Quota over BigQuery API in the same project as below?

User-1/Principal-1 - 50GB
User-2/Principal-2 - 10GB
User-3/Principal-3 - 1TB
User-4/Principal-4 - Unlimited

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe not possible.

There are 2 type of quotas.
A project level and general Users level.

While a project level quota is a pool, eg its consumed by everyone.
The user quota is per user account/service account and not per individual.

To understand better the user quota eg: you set 5GB.
User A can consume up to 5GB.
User B can also consume up to 5GB.
You cannot define who is user A or user B, it's just user/service account level.

There is a nice extended breakdown [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas#set-custom-quotas).

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Marton (Pentium10) is correct, but you can cheat!

The cheat is to create a project per "type of quotas".

- Project-1 - 50GB
- Project-2 - 10GB
- Project-3 - 1TB
- Project-4 - Unlimited

Then you grant the role BigQuery Job User on the accounts (user or service) on the projet with the quota of your choice.

Finally, you grant all the accounts on the data source (project hosting the BigQuery data) as BigQuery data viewer (if you only need to query, wider role if you need to update/delete data/table/dataset)

It's a bit cumbersome but it answer your requirement.